# How to make a helix placement path?

Tags: geometry

We are trying to create a helix path in scenekit. We searched through net and got below three equations for helix. When we put them the attached scene was generated in scenekit.

However we need certain modifications and more information on that helix - ... now the questions

[Current sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai5Lu.png)

**x(t)=Rcost, y(t)=Rsin(t), z(t)=at.**

**1. how to create the helix rotated to any direction?**

**2. What will be the angle of a small parts of helix?**

**3. So if we want to approximately make the helix with small small lines, what will be angle of those lines?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE! If you want precise answers.... well, be precise. Ad 1. Apply rotation matrix.

Comment: If you consider one round and flatten the helix you find a right angled triangle in which we can write: $tan \alpha = \frac{at}{2\pi R}$, where $\alpha $ is the angle of every small line during the building of helix, at is moving in Z direction and $ 2\pi R$ is circumference  of circle in one round.

Answer (score 0):

I will only give an answer to your first question, as I don't know what you mean by the phrases "small parts", "small lines" and "angle of those lines".

Given a helix
$$
H(t) = \begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t) \\ z(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} R\cos(t) \\ R\sin(t) \\ at \end{bmatrix}
$$
We can rotate it by multiplying with any rotation matrix $A$, for example to rotate it along the  $z$ axis by an angle $\theta$, use
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
The coordinates of the rotated helix will be given by the multiplication $AH(t)$:
$$A\cdot H(t) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} R\cos(t) \\ R\sin(t) \\ at \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} R(\cos(\theta)\cos(t)-\sin(\theta)\sin(t))\\ R(\sin(\theta) \cos(t)-\cos(\theta)\sin(t))\\ at \end{bmatrix}$$

For farther rotation matrix examples, read the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions) article.

Answer (score 0):

so a very dumb question here....

So, it seems that if we want to rotate the Helix by **any** angle around **any** rotation axis , then use the rotation matrix and matrix representation of the helix and do a matrix multiplication thereafter. (rotation Matrix equation from wiki below)

Is there a simpler method to do this, such as using original helix co-ordinate equations and using quaternion...?

Thanks in advance.

Text from wiki :-

The matrix of a proper rotation R by angle θ around the axis {\displaystyle \mathbf {u} =(u_{x},u_{y},u_{z})}{\displaystyle \mathbf {u} =(u_{x},u_{y},u_{z})}, a unit vector with {\displaystyle u_{x}^{2}+u_{y}^{2}+u_{z}^{2}=1}{\displaystyle u_{x}^{2}+u_{y}^{2}+u_{z}^{2}=1}, is given by:[3]

{\displaystyle R={\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta +u_{x}^{2}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)&u_{x}u_{y}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)-u_{z}\sin \theta &u_{x}u_{z}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)+u_{y}\sin \theta \\u_{y}u_{x}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)+u_{z}\sin \theta &\cos \theta +u_{y}^{2}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)&u_{y}u_{z}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)-u_{x}\sin \theta \\u_{z}u_{x}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)-u_{y}\sin \theta &u_{z}u_{y}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)+u_{x}\sin \theta &\cos \theta +u_{z}^{2}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)\end{bmatrix}}.}{\displaystyle R={\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta +u_{x}^{2}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)&u_{x}u_{y}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)-u_{z}\sin \theta &u_{x}u_{z}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)+u_{y}\sin \theta \\u_{y}u_{x}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)+u_{z}\sin \theta &\cos \theta +u_{y}^{2}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)&u_{y}u_{z}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)-u_{x}\sin \theta \\u_{z}u_{x}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)-u_{y}\sin \theta &u_{z}u_{y}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)+u_{x}\sin \theta &\cos \theta +u_{z}^{2}\left(1-\cos \theta \right)\end{bmatrix}}.}